# Program to generate non-static design spec docs?

Tags: software-recommendation, design-specifications

My design team has been using MS Word via Sharepoint to deliver UX specs to our developers. Our documents include a section for: final visuals, content, wireframes, interaction notes, and business analysis flows. In short, these MS word documents are NOT short and are impossible to navigate as they are static linear documents. I would not wish these documents on anyone.

What my team needs (no compromises):

- A design spec that contains IX, BA, Visuals, Content, & attached files
- Simultaneous editing
- Version control
- A non-linear format with navigation
- PC & Mac supported

What won't work: Axure, RTF docs & PDFs

What I heard others use: Zurb tools, Jira, a Wiki

**What solution would you strongly recommend?** Thanks in advanced for the help.

Comment: erm... HTML with a custom CMS? Universal, accessed from anywhere, and easy to maintain, backup, archive, etc.

Comment: Hi Andrew, If you do not receive an answer, I would also try posting this question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: or also try ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

> My design team has been using MS Word via Sharepoint to deliver UX specs to our developers

Heh. I've been there. I sympathize.

The problem is delivering UX specs. That means you're stuck in a waterfall process that avoids collaboration. As such, you can't ever succeed.

For this to work in a waterfall model, UX needs to take ownership of the presentation layer code and actually create the interactions. This then becomes the specification.

Anything short of that will always have big lost-in-translations issues no matter how heavily documented. In fact, I've found the heavier the documentation, the more confusion that it can lead to as developers start referring to month-old specs that have been updated 3 times since.

> What solution would you strongly recommend?

as you've probably guessed, I strongly recommend none of those. You're just setting your team up to be a documentation team, which no one wants, and no one really benefits from anyways.

The options that I've seen work to some degree (at least way better than the heavy documentation model) is:

- Switch to Agile Development (Lean UX) and/or...
- Have UX own the presentation layer and/or...
- Communicate constantly with the dev team. Have a lot of the specs come from joint collaboration--not a 2 month old document.

UX should never be a documentation/specification factory. They should be facilitators and sketchers. (One could argue that's how all members of the product team should operate).

Comment: Can you elaborate on "UX needs to take ownership of the presentation layer"?

Comment: @Andrew I'm a huge believer in the UX team being the ones that create the HTML, CSS and JS that influences the UI. I don't believe true interaction design can happen on paper or in Axure. It has to be crafted in the medium it will be used in. The most succesful UX<->Dev team relations I've been a part of have had people that straddle the two. Either the UX team has UI developers on their team and/or the UI Dev team has UX folks on their team. The deliverable is no longer a heavy specification document, but the actual product.

Comment: Where I've seen it fail miserably is when UX is 'responsible' for UI, but at the mercy of an entirely different dev team--often a vendor. What happens is that UX gets blamed for things like "well, the spec document wasn't detailed enough". But the reality is that no UX document can fully address every single interaction and scenario and issue that will come up during the process of actually building something. So if UX is going to take the heat for the UI, they might as well own the UI.

Comment: I see UX as contributors to thought leadership and driving designs/solutions based on a user centered vision. UX designers should own the creative process and solution design, not developing the solution as that would prevent designers from focusing on research and vision (there's only so much time in a day).  As the dev teams are in their sprint, designers should be involved in the process to ensure efficacy.

What you're referring to is not a UX designer IMHO, but an interaction developer.  And I don't see how the addition of an IX dev eliminates the need for documentation.

Comment: @Andrew we have very different opinions on that. :) I certainly agree that there needs to be focus on research and vision. What I am arguing for is for UX to not be *contributors* but *facilitators*. An IX dev working *with* the UX team means they don't need a document to tell them what to build. They are a *part* of the whole creative process and solution design. Don't take away from UX work to do IX work. Add IX work to the UX work that's already being done.

Comment: Another way to put it, you can't effectively spec IX unless you, yourself, are an IX developer. And if you are, you might as well just go ahead and build it. (I also vehemently argue that you can't do detailed IX work anyways in a spec document. You *have* to do it in the medium you are working in. (This is why I find Axure dangerous when taken to high fidelity)

Comment: (And I say all of this knowing that this is simply not how it's done in most large corporations. Alas, I have yet to see the 'document the IX' ever actually work in a large corporation, either.)

Comment: completely understand your point, I just don't know if it's feasible for me/my company. For example, I design a consumer product that works on Android, iOS, PC, Mac & Web. The product manifests itself differently on each device; some features are echoed and others specific to the OS/Device type. It's not possible for me to develop the front end for any of the native apps. Also, QA needs documentation for testing, and rules & flows need to be explicitly mapped for future designers/developers so they don't have to reverse engineer anything to add a feature or redeisgn.

Comment: Yea, I get that. And have done it. It's just how big companies want to work...producing lots of documentation. So, I do wish you luck!

Comment: The point is not to create superficial documentation, but to work as a team. To assign the right people to the right task. Your last comment doesn't address my concerns of how one person can develop the front-end on multiple platforms. Also, it doesn't address the need for QA, devs, & other designers to have documentation - it's just a jab at large companies.  For the record, I really am looking for a answer derived from experience (not just theory), something that can scale to larger companies.  If you can provide that, I would enjoy reading more of your perspective.

Comment: @Andrew it's not about one person, but about the roles being part of UX--or at the very least--tightly integrated with UX. So, a more practical example would be that UX in their wireframes say that a particular widget is 'Widget X'. Then UX would be working with the Android UI dev, the iOS Android UI dev, etc to collaborative with UX flesh out the IX and create a component that could be shared in a component library. I wish I could provide you something that would scale to larger companies on the documentation side, but that's the point I'm trying to make: UX documentation doesn't scale.

Comment: I'm now working with my 4th Fortune 500 and, alas, we end up having to deal with constantly outdated, duplicate, and insufficient UX documentation. We're *slowly* trying to move towards Agile, and Lean UX. But we have a long way to go. In the interim, I'd suggest doing research on *Lean UX*. The premise of *Lean UX* is to get out of the document management business and back into creating actual user experiences.